# Using $\int_{2}^{\infty } \frac{dx}{x^{n+1}} =\frac{1}{n 2^{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

find the sums of the series
$$\frac{1}{1\cdot 2}+\frac{1}{2\cdot 2^{2}}+\cdots +\frac{1}{n 2^{n}}$$

I solved this below, but did not know what my mistake is
But now the page asks me to provide additional context
Solution.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n 2^{n}}=
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\int_{2}^{\infty }\frac{dx}{x^{n+1}}=\int_{2}^{\infty }\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{dx}{x^{n+1}}=\int_{2}^{\infty }\frac{dx}{x(x-1)}$$

$$\int_{2}^{\infty }\frac{dx}{x(x-1)}=\lim_{b\to \infty }  \int_{2}^{b }(\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{x})dx=\lim_{b\to \infty } \left [  \ln(b-1 ) - \ln(b)+\ln(2)  \right  ] =\ln(2)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n 2^{n}}=
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\int_{2}^{\infty }\frac{dx}{x^{n+1}}=\int_{2}^{\infty }\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{dx}{x^{n+1}}=\int_{2}^{\infty }\frac{dx}{x(x-1)}$$

$$\int_{2}^{\infty }\frac{dx}{x(x-1)}=\lim_{b\to \infty }  \int_{2}^{b }(\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{x})dx=\lim_{b\to \infty } \left [  \ln(b-1 ) - \ln(b)+\ln(2)  \right  ] =\ln(2)$$

Comment: There’s sign error in the final step. Specifically, it is $$\lim_{b\to\infty}\left(\left.\ln(x-1)\right|^{b}_2-\left.\ln(x)\right|^{b}_2\right)\,,$$ which would rather evaluate to $$\lim_{b\to\infty}\ln\left(\frac{b-1}{b}\right)+\ln(2)=\ln(2)\,.$$

Comment: @JackLeGrüß Oh you are correct. I made a silly mistake. Now I have corrected.